# Use cholesky decomposition to compute eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When a matrix A, for example 2*2 matrix, is positive defined, the following steps can compute the eigenvalues of A,

$A_k = U_k^T*U_k$

$A_{k+1} = U_k*U_k^T$

Finally, $A_k = $$
    \begin{matrix}
    \lambda_1 & 0\\
    0 & \lambda_2 \\
    \end{matrix}
$ when $k = \infty$

why this procedure can reach the eigenvalues of A?